# Greek Alpha symbol

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is **greek Alpha symbol** ? and as per my requirement how to use greek Alpha symbol as a **logo** and as a **favicon** in HTML ?

Comment: http://www.lmg tfy.com/?q=greek+alpha+symbol   ,sorry lmg and t has space.Remove the space and hit url

Answer (score 2):

The Html Code is `&#945;` or `&alpha;`

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBXa7/)

If you want to use it as a favicon you need to create a icon ;)

- You can use e.g. [Faviconist](http://faviconist.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Greek Alpha symbols is `&alpha` or `&#945;`. To use it as favicon, make image with this symbol and upload to server.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha - this is alpha, wiki contains even the picture :-) You can write it as **&alpha**.

Favicon can be included to your web in several ways, I would try:

```
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="/somewhere/myicon.png" />
```

Other systems in short tutorial: http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Btw, favicon has to be 16x16 pixels or 32x32, other pictures are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know what some request means by “greek Alpha symbol”, but probably it means just the Greek letter alpha, and specifically lowercase alpha α, since uppercase alpha Α has the sama glyph as the Latin A. If you needed to use it as a *character* in HTML, you could simply write it as such or use a character reference. But since you specifically refer to a logo and a favicon, you just need to create suitable images and use them, like for logos and favicons in general.

For a logo, it is somewhat debatable what the `alt` text should contain in this case. The main options are probably

```
<img src=alpha.png alt=α>
<img src=alpha.png alt=alpha>
<img src=alpha.png alt="">
```

This depends on the context and purpose of using the logo.